# Surface with border is homotopy equivalent to bouquet of circles

Tags: general-topology, surfaces

Why is any compact surface with non-trivial boundary homotopy equivalent to bouquet of circles?

It was mentined in "Course homotopy topology" by Fomenko, Fuchs while calculating homotopy groups of compact surfaces, and I have not find any key to this task.

Comment: I'm not sure why this was closed as unclear - it's obvious you meant 'boundary' when you said border. I would have voted to close this question for not providing enough context however. Could you say what part of this problem you are having trouble with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Every compact surface with boundary can be built as a quotient along the boundary of a closed disk with $k$ open disks removed from its interior (where $k$ is the number of boundary components of the surface).

Comment: So one can retract it on a carcass of this circles and some added lines between them, which is just a graph?

Comment: @se0808 Yep. That's right.